# jQuery dialog won't close (with .load data)

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-dialog

On my page (let's call it page A) I have a jQuery dialog with the id `customOrderEdit`. Within the dialog I load another page (let's call it page B) using $("#customOrderEdit").load("/url/to/page.php").

Now I want to close the dialog using a custom button, but it won't close. I've tried so many things (found on google, stackoverflow, etc.) but none of them seem to work. It doesn't matter if the code to close the dialog are on page A or B, as long as it closes I'm happy.

Code I tried on page A:

```
$("body").on('click', '.cancelUpdateOrder', function(){
    console.log("Test"); //it displays the test console log, but it doesn't close
    $("#customOrderEdit).dialog( "close" );
    return false;
});
```

Code I tried on page B:

```
$(".cancelUpdateOrder").on('click', function(){
        $('#customOrderEdit').dialog('close');
        return false;
});
```

I've also tried to call the click function differently:

- `$(".cancelUpdateOrder").click(function(){ }});`
- `$(".cancelUpdateOrder").live('click', function(){ }});`
- `$(".cancelUpdateOrder").on('click', function(){ }});`.

And the closing part:

- `$(".ui-dialog").dialog( "close" );`
- `window.parent.$('#customOrderEdit').dialog('close');`
- `$('#customOrderEdit', window.parent).dialog("close");`

And probably some more I can't remember.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and can provide me the right code?

Comment: You are probably missing a **double quotes** i.e. `"` in Page A while referring `dialog box` - > `$("#customOrderEdit).dialog(` should have been `$("#customOrderEdit").dialog(`

Answer (score 0):

The class selector can return a list of objects, then you can try to iterate with them using **each**:

```
$('.cancelUpdateOrder').each( function () {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        $('#customOrderEdit').dialog('close');
        return false;
    })
});
```

If doesn't work, you can try to put a console.log to track if you are reaching the right elements.

Hope it helps

Comment: that doesn't work for me @Ricardo. The element is reached in my case inside the button click event and I get a `console.log` output but the reference to the `$('#myDialogName').dialog('close');` doesn't have any effect on the dialog sadly :(. Similar to Femke, I tried several approaches, got a object reference to the dialog just after initializing it and then binding a click event to the button, in that case it works fine, *but  only the first time I open the dialog*, the next time the dialog is launched, the *close* button is unresponsive, it doesn't even reach the event handler. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and commented out the jquery.js included in the file being loaded (file B) even though it was the exact same jquery.js file that had been included in the calling file (file A).  The following example will **NOT** work unless you comment out the `<script src...>` tag in the test.php file that is loaded into the dialog.

test.html (I am using jquery-3.2.1 and jquery-ui 1.12.1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="contentsContainer">
    <button id="btnAddClient" name="btnAddClient">Add</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#contentsContainer").on('click', '#btnAddClient', function () {
        var dlg = $("<div id=\"btnAddClientDlg\"/>").dialog({
            title: 'Add New Client',
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 720,
            height: 420,
            buttons: {
                Save: function () {
                    $.post("../php/test.php");
                    $('#btnAddClientDlg').dialog('destroy').remove();

                },
                Close: function () {
                    $('#btnAddClientDlg').dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        dlg.load("../php/test.php");
        dlg.dialog('open');
    });
});
```

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<header>
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</header>
<?php
    echo "hello";
?>
```